# Google Sheets formula for summing/averaging with specific conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, average

I am hoping for a formula to take hours from the name columns and sum/average them by week, into a separate table like the 2nd one below. The formulas need to update upon changing the start and end week cells.

| Body Part | Start Week | End Week | Arnold (hours) | Usain (hours) | Bob (hours) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arms | 1 | 3 | 6 | 3 | 0 |
| Legs | 1 | 6 | 12 | 36 | 20 |
| Chest | 2 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| Booty | 4 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 3 |
| Core | 1 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 5 |

Formula Needed:

| Hours | Arnold | Usian | Bob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week 1 | 6 | 8 | 4.33 |
| Week 2 | 8 | 8.67 | 5 |
| Week 3 | 8 | 8.67 | 5 |
| Week 4 | 9 | 11.67 | 6 |
| Week 5 | 7 | 11 | 5.33 |
| Week 6 | 5 | 10 | 4.33 |

Bonus if there is a way to also quickly average hours by body parts if for example there are multiple Arms rows.

Comment: shouldnt Arnold week 1 be 28 (sum of 6+12+10) ? and average 9.33 ?

Comment: It is dividing the hours along the total weeks so more like
Arnold arms: 6 hours from weeks 1-3 = 2 hours a week, Legs = 2 hours a week and core = 2 hours a week adding up to 6 hours week 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(a, b, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(BYCOL(D1:F1, LAMBDA(xx, FLATTEN(IF(
 IF(a>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(a)), "Week "&TEXT(SEQUENCE(1, MAX(a))+b, "00"), )="",,
 REGEXEXTRACT(OFFSET(xx,,,1), "(.+) \(")&"×"&
 IF(a>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(a)), "Week "&TEXT(SEQUENCE(1, MAX(a))+b, "00"), )&"×"&
 QUERY({REGEXEXTRACT(OFFSET(xx,,,1), "(.+) \("); OFFSET(xx,1,,9^9)/(a)}, "offset 1", )))))), "×"), 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3>0 group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
 (C2:INDEX(C:C, MAX(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>"")))-B2:INDEX(B:B, MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>"")))+1, 
                                         B2:INDEX(B:B, MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>"")))-1))
```

[image]